# VScode plugin for angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is there a VSCode plugin, which --- can cross check a variable in app.component.html, to see if it exists in the app.component.ts file, and highlight it to me if there is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `Angular Essentials extension pack for VS Code`. This should have what you need.